# Restoring from cloud with TI backup

Tags: restore, titanium-backup, cloud

I had to flash/reset my phone so everything is back to new. I had used Titanium Backup pro to backup everything to Google Drive. I had used encryption. Now how do I get things back? In particular how do I restore from the cloud? I connected to Google Drive, but those backups don't show under the Backup/Restore tab? TI backup is confusing to use.

Comment: Can you see the backup on your cloud , without using the app?

Comment: @beeshyams yes everything is there and I can view it through Google Drive's web interface

Comment: That's strange. Let's wait for solutions